Equivalent definitions of convergence. Neighborhood or open set?
Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space and let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $X$. We say that $x_n$ converges to $x$ iff for every open set $U$ with $x \in U$ exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $x_n \in U, \ \forall n \geq n_0$.
Why can we replace the notion of open set $U$ with $x \in U$ by:

$U$ neighborhood of $x$?

(We say $W \subset X$ is a neighborhood of an element $x \in X$ if there exists $G \in \tau$ such that $x \in G \subset W$.)

$U$ belonging to a neighborhood basis of $x$?

(We say $\mathcal{F}_x$ is a neighborhood basis of $x$ if $x \in V$ for every $V \in \mathcal{F}_x$ and for every $G \in \tau$ with $x \in G$ exists $V \in \mathcal{F}_x$ such that $V \subset G$.)
It is clear that:

If we have the property for $U$ belonging to a neighborhood basis of $x$ then we have it for $U$ neighborhood of $x$ and $U$ open set with $x \in U$.
If we have the property for $U$ open set with $x \in U$ then we have it for $U$ neighborhood of $x$.

What about the other implications?

$U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ if $U\in \tau$ and $x\in U$...

Some books use a different definition of neighborhood. @Surb Specifically, the alternate definition is any subset that contains a neighborhood in your sense.

I fail to see why the other implications would be more difficult than the ones you already sketched.

I think by neighborhood, you mean a basis element of the topology.  Since every basis element (or neighborhood) is by definition open, and since every open set containing $x$ contains a basis element containing $x$, you can clearly replace open set in the definition of convergence by neighborhood.

@Mths: recall that open sets containing $x$ are neighborhoods of $x$. And, regards the definition of basis of neighborhoods, the first condition is that each element of the basis of neighborhoods of $x$ is a neighborhood of $x$. Instead of just containing $x$. Notice that the set ${x}$ verifies both conditions, but it isn't necessarily a neighborhood of $x$, as it isn't necessarily open.

Exactly! I totally see that open sets containing x are neighborhoods of x, so that would prove the equivalence "neighborhood of x and open set containing x".
With reference to your second remark, do you mean that my definition of basis of neighborhoods of x is wrong? I should say then that  each element of the basis of neighborhoods of x is a neighborhood of x + the second condition, right?

Indeed, @Maths. And now, the equivalence would follow, as the elements of the basis of neighborhoods of $x$ are neighborhoods $x$.

I am glad that my comment has been helpful. I can put the comments together as an answer if your doubts have been cleared.

Now everything makes perfect sense. I think my doubts have been all cleared. Thank you!

Great! You're welcome!

For the pending implication in the first equivalence, recall that open sets containing $x$ are neighborhoods of $x$.
Regards the definition of basis of neighborhoods of a point, the first condition is that each element of the basis of neighborhoods of $x$ is a neighborhood of $x$. Instead of just containing $x$. Notice that the set $\{x\}$ verifies both conditions, but it isn't necessarily a neighborhood of $x$, as it isn't necessarily open.
Now, the pending implication in the second equivalence follows, as the elements of the basis of neighborhoods of $x$ are neighborhoods $x$.
